# Simple query language help in InfluxDB - creating an aggregate table

Tags: aggregate, influxdb

I'm trying to learn the query language of InfluxDB to create an aggregate table, but I'm having issues. Here is my conundrum.
Say I have a table like this:

name: temperature

time | value | metric |      measurement

X    |   25  |  degrees(C)   |  temperature

X    |   10   | degrees(C)    |   temperature

and one like this

name: cpu_usage

time | metric   | value | measurement

X    | %usage    | 73   |   cpu_usage

X     | %usage   |  75  |   cpu_usage

How can I get these into a table like this:

name:aggregate

time | measurement | metric       | mean value

X    | temperature |   degrees(C) |       17.5

X     | cpu_usage     | %usage         |  74

basically, I want to create another table with the mean values from different tables. however, i ALSO want to preserve some of the column names from other tables. Right now, I'm having the issue that you can't mix aggregate and non-aggregate functions, so it won't let me do "SELECT metric, measurement, mean(value) FROM cpu_usage INTO aggregate. And, I have no idea how to merge/join tables (I don't think it's supported anymore), so if i were to calculate the average, store it in a temp table, i wouldn't know how to then combine it with the current tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell from your example above whether `metric` and `measurement` are tags or fields. Assuming that they are tags so the data you're working with looks like the following

```
temperature,metric=degrees(C),measurement=temperature value=25 X
temperature,metric=degrees(C),measurement=temperature value=10 X

cpu_usage,metric=%usage,measurement=cpu_usage value=75 X
cpu_usage,metric=%usage,measurement=cpu_usage value=73 X
```

Then the queries

```
SELECT mean(value) as usage INTO aggregate FROM cpu_usage GROUP BY *
SELECT mean(value) as temp INTO aggregate FROM temperature GROUP BY *
```

Should give you the output you're looking for.

**That being said, this is not a best practice**.

I would recommend doing something more like the following:

Write points that look like:

```
temperature,metric=degrees(C) value=25 X
temperature,metric=degrees(C) value=10 X

cpu_usage,metric=%usage value=75 X
cpu_usage,metric=%usage value=73 X
```

And have queries that write the measurements into different [retention policies](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.13/guides/downsampling_and_retention/#retention-policies):

```
SELECT mean(value) as value INTO mydb.aggregate.cpu_usage FROM cpu_usage GROUP BY *
SELECT mean(value) as value INTO mydb.aggregate.temperature FROM temperature GROUP BY *
```